# Can I check object is nill in Rails3 view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements

I'm trying to display a message if no transactions found. For that, I thought in the view I could use something like `<% if @current_account.transactions.nill? %> puts "No transactions yet" <% end %>` unfortunately this is not valid.

Any suggestion?

Comment: puts "No transactions yet" if @current_account.transactions.nill? perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The code should be

```
<% if @current_account.transactions.nil? %>
```

and not

```
<% if @current_account.transactions.nill? %>
```

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

transactions is an array so @current_account.transactions will return an empty array which is not nil?.my suggestion is to use

```
    @current_acccount.transactions.empty?
```

check

```
  irb(main):011:0> u=User.new=> #<User id: nil, email: "",....
  irb(main):012:0> u.companies=>[]
  irb(main):013:0> u.companies.nil?=>false
  irb(main):015:0> u.companies.empty?=>true
```